# Problem in sizing image when using z-index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**When i don't specify the position of my sections, the phone image perfectly follows the assigned width.**

Which is - `width: 60%;`

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

---

**But when i apply `position` and `z-index` to the first two sections the `width: 60%;` doesn't get applied, as the phone image becomes way too large.**

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

---

**HTML & CSS code:**

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#title {
    background-color: #ff4c68;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    Line-height: 1.5;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding: 3% 15% 7%;
}

p {
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    color: #8f8f8f;
}


/* Navigation Bar */

.navbar-brand {
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.navbar {
    padding-bottom: 4.5em;
}

.nav-item {
    padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: 100;
}


/* Download buttons */

.download-button {
    margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
}


/* Title image */

.title-image {
    width: 60%;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    position: absolute;
}


/* feature section  */

#features {
    padding: 7% 15%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.feature-box {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5%;
}

.icon {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    color: #ef8172;
}

.icon:hover {
    color: #ff4c68;
}


/* testimonials */

#testimonials {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ef8172;
    color: #fff;
}

.carousel-item {
    padding: 7% 15%;
}

.testimonial-image {
    width: 10%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
}


/* Press */

#press {
    background-color: #ef8172;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.press-logo {
    width: 15%;
    padding: 20px 20px 50px;
}


/* Pricing  */

#pricing {
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.pricing-col {
    padding: 3% 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TinDog</title>

    <!-- Bootstap css  -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS Stylesheets  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap scripts  -->
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <!-- font awesome  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />


</head>

<body>

    <section id="title">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- Nav Bar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href=""> tindog</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>



            <!-- Title -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img class="title-image" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <!-- Features -->

    <section id="features">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="feature-box col-md-4">
                <i class="icon fas fa-check-circle fa-5x"></i>
                <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
                <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
            </div>
            <div class=" feature-box col-md-4">
                <i class="icon fas fa-bullseye fa-5x"></i>
                <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
                <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
            </div>
            <div class=" feature-box col-md-4">
                <i class="icon fas fa-heart fa-5x"></i>
                <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
                <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>


    <!-- Testimonials -->

    <section id="testimonials">
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="3000">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
                    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
                    <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
                    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
                    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
        </div>





    </section>


    <!-- Press -->

    <section id="press">
        <img class="press-logo" src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
        <img class="press-logo" src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
        <img class="press-logo" src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
        <img class="press-logo" src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

    </section>


    <!-- Pricing -->

    <section id="pricing">

        <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
        <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="pricing-col col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2>Free</h2>
                        <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
                        <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
                        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                        <div class="d-grid col-6 mx-auto">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-col col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3>Labrador</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
                        <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
                        <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
                        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                        <div class="d-grid col-6 mx-auto">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-col col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3>Mastiff</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
                        <p>Pirority Listing</p>
                        <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
                        <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
                        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                        <div class="d-grid col-6 mx-auto">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <!-- Call to Action -->

    <section id="cta">

        <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
        <button type="button">Download</button>
        <button type="button">Download</button>

    </section>


    <!-- Footer -->

    <footer id="footer">

        <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>

    </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

---

**I want the end result to be like this:**

[image: img5]

---

*image of the phone:*

[image]

Comment: Use the "img-fluid" to the class of img

Comment: Could you try replacing the .title-image { position : relative } . I believe this should solve what you asked else please be specific.

Comment: i tried using 'img-fluid', but nothing happened. Changing the position to relative, reverts the image back to 60% with no overlapping with z-index. To be specific, i want the features section to overlap the phone image as shown in the desired result image posted in the question.

Comment: Love it. please tell me this is a real project...

Comment: I'm learning this from a course i enrolled in. [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-web-development-bootcamp/)
Should i post it on my GitHub if its good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only really need to set the `position` of your first section to achieve this, if you set the `title`'s `position: relative;` and `z-index: -1;`, you won't need to set the position on your `.title-image` class. See the snippet(Full page) below for your reference.

Here is the snippet's result: [image: result]

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#title {
  background-color: #ff4c68;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 90%;
  max-height: 900px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding-inline: 10%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  Line-height: 1.5;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15% 7%;
}

p {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  color: #8f8f8f;
}


/* Navigation Bar */

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.navbar {
  padding-bottom: 4.5em;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 100;
}


/* Download buttons */

.download-button {
  margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
}


/* Title image */

.title-image {
  width: 70%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}


/* feature section  */

#features {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.feature-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}

.icon {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #ef8172;
}

.icon:hover {
  color: #ff4c68;
}


/* testimonials */

#testimonials {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ef8172;
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-item {
  padding: 7% 15%;
}

.testimonial-image {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}


/* Press */

#press {
  background-color: #ef8172;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.press-logo {
  width: 15%;
  padding: 20px 20px 50px;
}


/* Pricing  */

#pricing {
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pricing-col {
  padding: 3% 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <!-- Bootstap css  -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS Stylesheets  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <!-- Google fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap scripts  -->
  <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- font awesome  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href=""> tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- Title -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img class="title-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz7Pc.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Features -->
  <section id="features">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-box col-md-4">
        <i class="icon fas fa-check-circle fa-5x"></i>
        <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
        <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>
      <div class=" feature-box col-md-4">
        <i class="icon fas fa-bullseye fa-5x"></i>
        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>
      <div class=" feature-box col-md-4">
        <i class="icon fas fa-heart fa-5x"></i>
        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Testimonials -->
  <section id="testimonials">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="3000">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Press -->
  <section id="press">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

  </section>


  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="pricing-col col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>Free</h2>
            <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
            <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <div class="d-grid col-6 mx-auto">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing-col col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Labrador</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
            <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
            <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <div class="d-grid col-6 mx-auto">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing-col col-lg-4 col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Mastiff</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
            <p>Pirority Listing</p>
            <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
            <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <div class="d-grid col-6 mx-auto">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Call to Action -->
  <section id="cta">
    <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
  </section>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="footer">
    <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

You can familiarize yourself with css `position` property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp).

PS. I won't be including any `@media` queries as it isn't part of the question.

Comment: Snippet not working- _stacksnippets.net took too long to respond._ 
Tried the CSS but it does not give the desired result.

Comment: I've included the image of the result from the snippet in my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Hey buddy I really don't know if this is the correct way of doing it, but it seems to work just fine. What I did was change the width to max width the make it from 60% to 18%. It looks good and like the lesson. then when you switch it to tablet or mobile, I had the @media function change it back to 60% so it didn't shrink all the way down and look weird. idk if I'm explaining it correctly but here's the code:

```
    .title-image {
      max-width: 18%;
      transform: rotate(25deg);
      position: absolute;
      right: 22%;
      }

      @media (max-width: 991px) {
       .title-image {
       position: static;
       transform: rotate(0deg);
       max-width: 60%;
        }
         }
```

I'm a complete beginner like you but I hope this helped in any way.

Comment: Thanks mate, it did work. Ill also wait for others to post an explanation to this problem, till then i will stick to this.

Comment: This is a working solution.